# Object not an instance of desired class

Tags: php

The following is what I have in index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/controllers/trackercontroller.php';

$oTracker = new trackerController();
var_dump($oTracker);
?>
```

and the output for oTracker is

```
object(trackerController)#1 (0) { }
```

And my trackerController in controllers/trackercontroller.php is

```
class trackerController{
    public $test = "hi";
    function __construct($oReader){

}
```

Why am I unable to view the class property test when I `var_dump()` the object?

Comment: You don't happen to have a second `trackerController` class somewhere, perhaps with/without a namespace...?

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed? If yes, it can limit the level of objects being displayed. If you do, try adding this before the var_dump ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth',2);

Answer (score 1):

You should have to follow object oriented concept for PHP like

```
use \controller\TrackerController;

$oTracker = new TrackerController();
var_dump($oTracker->test);
```

Here TrackerController is the class name.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: OOP works just as well without namespaces. Yes, namespaces are good, but not required for "object oriented concept".